# Camera not saving image and drops exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, camera, fileoutputstream

I'm creating camera app. I'm doing that in fragment. I have `FrameLayout` where I add the camera, and one button for capture. There are 2 problems.

1. Camera not saves the image.
2. When I click second time on capture image, drops exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed`

I don't know where's the problem, I'm using camera API first time.

Camera I'm using only in portrait mode. And in manifests I added the permissions for camera and write external storage.

I have one class where I'm extending `SurfaceView`. Let me show you the code.

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceHolder holder;

public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size mSize = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes){
        mSize = size;
    }

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    params.setRotation(90);

    params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}
}
```

Ok and here's the fragment for camera.

```
public class CameraActivity extends BaseFragment{
View mainView;
FrameLayout cameraLayout;
Camera camera;
ShowCamera showCamera;
ImageButton captureImage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    cameraLayout = (FrameLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.cameraContainer);
    captureImage = (ImageButton) mainView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    camera = Camera.open();
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(getActivity(), camera);

    cameraLayout.addView(showCamera);

    capture();

    return mainView;
}

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        if(bytes != null){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            if(bitmap != null){
                File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)));
                if(!file.isDirectory()){
                    file.mkdir();
                }

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();

                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

public void capture(){
    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(camera != null){
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in a emulator or in a real device?

Comment: In 2 real devices.